# Case Record Types vs Picklist value on case

Tags: servicecloud

We are starting a Service Cloud implementation and getting requirements from the user community about different types of requests that they handle. Is there a good rule of thumb on when to create a record type vs just using a picklist field on the case with various request types.

Some examples can be different types of booking requests (external vs internal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary advantages of using recordTypes are:

- you can restrict record access by profile
- you can assign a different page layout (to show different fields)

If you don't need either of those things, then it probably makes more sense to use a picklist. Deploying recordTypes is a pain because it requires deploying/re-creating the permissions in your target org(s).